# Differentiating variables and IDs

Tags: javascript, html

I am confused about the relationship between the

1. `var userInput` in line 3
2. the `userInput` in line 4
3. the id `userInput` in line 8

Specifically, does the `userInput` in line 4 (on the right side of `=`) refer to the `var userInput` in line 3? Or is it referring to the id `userInput` in line 8?

Also, how does the variable `userInput` in line 3 get used after it is assigned the `document.getelementbyID('userInput').value`?

```
1  <script type = "text/javascript">
2  function changeText2() {
3      var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
4      document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = userInput;
5  }
6  </script>
7  <p>Welcome to the site <b id = 'boldStuff2'>dude</b></p>
8  <input type = 'text' id = 'userInput' value = 'Enter Text Here'/>
9  <input type = 'button' onclick = 'changeText2()' value = 'Change Text'/>
```

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: @HoangLong is it better now? sorry don`t know how to do more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript variable names and DOM ids are not related and do not interact in any way. You have one variable `userInput` on line 3 and 4. You also have one DOM element with the id `"userInput"` on line 8, which is referenced on line 3 in `getElementById('userInput')`.

Maybe this illustrates it better:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeText2(){
        var userInputVariable = document.getElementById('userInputId').value;
        document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = userInputVariable;
    }
</script>
<p>Welcome to the site <b id='boldStuff2'>dude</b> </p> 
<input type='text' id='userInputId' value='Enter Text Here' />
```

> Also, how does the variable userInput in line 3 get used after it is assigned the `document.getelementbyID('userInput').value`?

The variable holds the value of `document.getElementById('userInputId').value`. This value is then assigned to `document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML` on the next line. You could do the same thing with:

```
document.getElementById('boldStuff2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('userInputId').value;
```

The variable goes out of scope after this (it basically ceases to exist), as the function ends.

Answer (score 1):

Line 3 declares a local variable (the `var userInput` part) that holds the results of running  `document.getElementById('userInput').value`. That basically tells the browser to go find the element on the page that has an `id` attribute with a value of "userInput" and get its value. Line 4 is telling the browser to go get the element on the page with an `id` attribute with a value of "boldStuff2" and set its contents to the value of the variable declared on line 3.

Comment: Thank you. Related question.  the variable in line 3 and the id in line 8 share the same name. Therefore, how does userInput in line 4 know whether the coder is referring to the variable in line 3 or the id in line 8?

Comment: @mjmitche As @deceze answered, HTML attributes don't have anything to do with JavaScript variables.

Answer (score 1):

The value entered in the input gets stored in the "VAR" userInput ...

The "Dude" in the html would get replaced with whatever what typed in that input box which was stored in userInput..

And to answer your question...

> Specifically, does the userInput in
>   line 4 (on the right side of =) refer
>   to the var userInput in line 3? or is
>   it referring to the id userInput in
>   line 8?

it refers to the Var in line 3...

> Also, how does the variable userInput
>   in line 3 get used after it is
>   assigned the
>   document.getelementbyID(userInput).value
>   ????

Think of it as holding a value for you... it just copies the value into it... so that when it is used in line 4 the value gets copied there...

You should just try running it in a browser and tinker with the code you will figure out what it is doing quicker that way.

Answer (score 1):

The two first userInput is javascript code, and the last is HTML.

Let me explain it step by step:

At the end of your code, there's a button 'Change Text' which invoke function changeText2() if it's clicked.

In changeText2:

1. userInput is assigned the value of the element which has id 'userInput'. In this case, that's the textbox content. (line 3)
2. Then, the textbox content is inserted inside the element 'boldStuff2', by innerHTML property. (line 4)

Last but not least, I recommend you reading about the basics javascript & html first.

Comment: thanks, I got this tutorial from reading a beginnner tutorial. the use of the same name (userInput ) for Javascript and html got me confused

Comment: @mjmitche: maybe I understand more now. Your problem is that you don't quite understand how HTML and javascript work together. In short: the id in HTML code is just a name, it's not a variable. That name could be referred by javascript code, to get the HTML content by provided methods (like getElementById - notice, it's case-sensitive). Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Specifically, does the userInput in line 4 (on the right side of =) refer to the var userInput in line 3? Or is it referring to the id userInput in line 8?

The variable `userInput` which you declared within the `changeText2()` function has been assigned the value of `document.getElementById('userInput').value` (line 3).

Essentially, this line looks for a HTML element on the page with the ID of `userInput`. This is the `<input>` defined on line 8.  Its `value` is then sent to a JavaScript variable, which happens to be called `userInput`.

Line 4 then uses the value in `userInput` as the `innerHTML` of an element on the page with the ID `boldStuff2`.